# Can't access remote MySQL

Tags: mysql

I got a VPS with CentOS, the only thing I have done is install MySQL for testing purposes.

When trying to connect from my pc I got this:

```
mysql -u root  -p -h [REMOTE-IP]
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'fixed[MyIP].totalplay.net' (using password: NO)
```

Weirdly it says using password=no, even when I put the -p and I got prompt it for it.

I did mysql_secure_installation:

1. Changed root password
2. Allowed root remote connection(testing, so no biggies there)

Still no luck.

I know I'm hitting the remote MySQL because I got "ERROR 1045 (28000)", nonetheless I checked:

1 Netstat on remote server, showing that is listening on 3306(OOTB port) and bind-address is on 0.0.0.0 ( allow anywhere)

```
netstat -tuplen | grep 3306
tcp        0      **0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:***               LISTEN      27         14923343   12002/mysqld
```

2 Telnet from local to remote to check that port is open and reachable

```
  telnet [REMOTE-IP] 3306         
    Trying [REMOTE-IP]...
    Connected to [REMOTE-IP]
```

I checked the user table

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user where user='root';
+------+-------------------------------------+
| user | host                                |
+------+-------------------------------------+
| root | %                                   |
| root | fixed[My-IP].totalplay.net |
| root | localhost                           |
+------+-------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The users were create this way:

CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASS';
CREATE USER 'root'@'fixed[My-IP].totalplay.net' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASS';

The one @localhost was of course already created

So the user does exists, checked the grants:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------
mysql> show grants for root;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


 mysql> show grants for 'root'@'fixed[My-IP].totalplay.net';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@fixed[My-IP].totalplay.net                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'fixed[My-IP].totalplay.net' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I also:

1 Created another user @ my ip, fixed[My-IP].totalplay.net and '%', granted privileges; same issue

2 Turned off firewall

3 Tried to connect using python, got similar results

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'fixed[MyIP].totalplay.net' (using password: YES)
```

The only difference is that now it says I'm using password.

My /etc/my.cnf

```
cat /etc/my.cnf
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]
performance-schema=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
innodb_buffer_pool_size=25165824
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=40000
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: i think it is better if you bit allow direct connections to your server it can be easily compromised and like always, you need all times luck the attacker only once. The problem would be the firewall, that blocks that port, what is very sensible. better is a REST approach and for all other purposes establish a ssh channel nd connect through there4

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention I have my firewall off, but if the firewall was on, when I run mysql -h [REMOTE-IP] wouldn't it be rejected even before I got there?

I think the same for the approach in most of the cases, in this case, I'm copying from a public rest service about 2 gb of data that is limited to 10 request per second to make it available for a personal project, so even if the data is breached, is public. 

With the SSH channel, u mean like doing a tunnel to redirect from local to remote? Haven't tried that option

Comment: @FernandoCarrilloCastro How have you set the passwords for the three different `root` accounts?

Comment: @FernandoCarrilloCastro Does it work when you remove the login with the specified hostname and use the login with the wildcard `%` host instead?

Comment: @FernandoCarrilloCastro Please verify/recheck that the MySQL server is indeed responding with "(using password: NO)" although you entered a password. The "Enter password:" prompt itself is not enough, you actually have to enter a password.

Comment: The `Access Denied` message includes a hyphen `-` after the word `fixed`. Your user table listing does not. Are you sure you've used the correct name when setting up the user?

Comment: @Progman 
CREATE USER 'root'@'[IP|%]' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASS';

Comment: @Progman 

So far, hasn’t work. The user ‘root’@‘%’ was my first choice and didn’t work, hence why the others were created 

I do get prompted for password, I put it, press enter and then get the error.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular
Sorry about that, typo trying to masquerade my IP, but is the same